# Forwarding a reference to a class as another type

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, reinterpret-cast, perfect-forwarding

I have code like the following that accepts a `std::aligned_storage_t` parameter by forwarding reference and is supposed to `reinterpret_cast` that into another type and return it to the user.

```
template <typename AlignedStorageType, typename TypeToReturnAs>
decltype(auto) forward_as_another_type(AlignedStorageType&& storage) {
    return *reinterpret_cast<TypeToReturnAs*>(&storage);
}
```

Is there a good way to maintain the type of reference that `storage` is in the return type?  For example if storage was an rvalue reference then I would want the return type to also be an rvalue reference.

Comment: Would a return value of `typename remove_reference<T>::type&&` as in std::move help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, flip the template parameters. You want `AlignedStorageType` to be deduced and the other to be explicitly specified:

```
template <typename TypeToReturnAs, typename AlignedStorageType>
decltype(auto) forward_as_another_type(AlignedStorageType&& storage) {
    return *reinterpret_cast<TypeToReturnAs*>(&storage);
}
```

Next, what you basically want is to conditionally cast the expression. If `AlignedStorageType&&` is an `X&&`, you want to cast it to a `TypeToReturnAs&&`. If it's an `X&`, as `TypeToReturnAs&`. If an `X const&`, as `TypeToReturnAs const&`.

We can add a type trait to just match the reference:

```
template <class T, class U> struct match_reference;
template <class T, class U> struct match_reference<T&, U>       { using type = U&; };
template <class T, class U> struct match_reference<T const&, U> { using type = U const&; };
template <class T, class U> struct match_reference<T&&, U>      { using type = U&&; };
template <class T, class U> using match_reference_t = typename match_reference<T,U>::type;
```

And then:

```
template <typename TypeToReturnAs, typename AlignedStorageType>
decltype(auto) forward_as_another_type(AlignedStorageType&& storage) {
    using R = match_reference_t<AlignedStorageType&&, TypeToReturnAs>;
    return static_cast<R>(*reinterpret_cast<TypeToReturnAs*>(&storage));
}
```

Alternatively, if you're only using this as a one-off, you can just write that logic as a conditional:

```
template <typename TypeToReturnAs, typename AlignedStorageType>
decltype(auto) forward_as_another_type(AlignedStorageType&& storage) {
    using R = std::conditional_t<
        std::is_lvalue_reference<AlignedStorageType>::value,
        TypeToReturnAs&, 
        TypeToReturnAs&&>;
    return static_cast<R>(*reinterpret_cast<TypeToReturnAs*>(&storage));
}
```

or:

```
    using R = std::conditional_t<
        std::is_lvalue_reference<AlignedStorageType>::value,
        TypeToReturnAs&, 
        TypeToReturnAs>;
    return std::forward<R>(*reinterpret_cast<TypeToReturnAs*>(&storage));
```

Comment: Thanks!  This is awesome!  I intended `AlignedStorageType` to be deduced in my code.  I was just wondering if there was another way to do this other than just making a custom trait.

Comment: Could you explain why in the last example the third parameter to `std::conditional_t` is `TypeToReturnAs` and not `TypeToReturnAs&&`?

Comment: @Curious It's the same either way, since `forward<T>` gives you back a `T&&`. It's just a bit shorter and fits common usage of `forward` better (like, you don't write `std::forward<T&&>(x)` typically).

Comment: But `std::forward` has two overloads, one which accepts an rvalue and one that accepts an lvalue (by the fact that one accepts an lvalue reference and the other an rvalue reference), then won't the last example always match the one with the lvalue reference?  since the dereferenced value from the `reinterpret_cast` is not an rvalue (xvalue or prvalue).  Or am I wrong?

Comment: @Curious Yes, it will always match the one with the lvalue reference. Same way as when you write `std::forward<T>(x)`, you're calling the lvalue reference overload regardless of whether you're moving or not, because `x` is always an lvalue.

Comment: I get it, because of reference collapsing internally, `TypeToReturnAs& &&` -> `TypeToReturnAs&` and `TypeToReturnAs &&` -> `TypeToReturnAs&&`